# How to create all $1$'s vectors of length $n$ without using Tuples[]?

Tags: list-manipulation, tuples, concatenation

I am having problems with creating a vector of 1s of length (for example) n=4.

I tried

```
ones=Tuples[{1},4]
```

This outputs {{$1,1,1,1$}}

The problem I have here, is that I want to concatenate this $1$'s vector with an identity matrix. See below, I transpose the ones vector to get a column vector

```
onesT = Transpose[ones]
```

The above command outputs {{$1$},{$1$},{$1$},{$1$}} (which I think is what I want because it denotes a $4 \times 1$ column vector)

I then join with the $4 \times 4$ identity matrix in order to achieve my desired matrix.

```
identity = IdentityMatrix[4]

matrix = Join[identity, onesT]
```

However, this outputs {{$1,0,0,0$},{$0,1,0,0$},{$0,0,1,0$},{$0,0,0,1$},{$1$},{$1$},{$1$},{$1$}}

But I want it to output {{$1,0,0,0$},{$0,1,0,0$},{$0,0,1,0$},{$0,0,0,1$},{$1,1,1,1$}}.

Is there a way of either:

- Creating a vector of $1$'s of length $n$, other than using Tuples[], so as to avoid the formatting issues
- Concatenating these two matrices (onesT and identity) so as to avoid formatting issues (I tried to use Flatten[] at various stages in the code, and this did not seem to work)

Comment: How about: `n = 4;
Join[IdentityMatrix[n], {ConstantArray[1, n]}]` ?

Comment: Or perhaps: `onesT = Table[1, 4]
identity = IdentityMatrix[4]
matrix = Join[identity, {onesT}]`

Comment: Or `Join[IdentityMatrix[n], ConstantArray[1, {1, n}]]`.

Comment: Also, `SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 1, {n + 1, _} -> 1}, {n + 1, n}]` or even `SparseArray[{i_, i_} | {n + 1, _} -> 1, {n + 1, n}]`.

Comment: Something that has not been advocated yet: keep your original in the following manner: `ones = Tuples[{1}, 4]
identity = IdentityMatrix[4]
matrix = Join[identity, ones]`

Comment: Or why not `matrix = Join[identity, ones]` and dispense with `Transpose` (or `Join[IdentityMatrix[4], Tuples[{1},4]]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
ArrayPad[IdentityMatrix[n], {{0, 1}, {0, 0}}, 1]
```

Or

```
PadRight[IdentityMatrix[n], {n + 1, n}, 1]
```

Or

```
Insert[IdentityMatrix[n], ConstantArray[1, n], -1]
```

Answer (score 5):

You almost got the result you wanted, but somewhere you took a
wrong turn. The question states

> The problem I have here, is that I want to concatenate this 1's vector with an identity matrix.

The direct code which seems to give the requested output is

```
ones = Tuples[{1},4];
identity = IdentityMatrix[4];
matrix = Join[ identity, ones]
(* {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 1}} *)
```

This produces a $5\times4$ matrix. However, the question
also states

> See below, I transpose the ones vector to get a column vector

This is where the wrong turn takes place. There was no need to
use a column vector here. The use of `Join` with matrices having
the same number of columns is essentially maintaining the rows of
the matrices involved to form the rows of the "joined" matrix.

If, instead, the requirement was to maintain columns, then the
use of `MapThread` with `Join` would have to be used.

Comment: The OP wanted a {5,4} matrix. Your solution produces a {4,5} matrix.

Comment: @lericr Thanks for that comment! I will try to fix my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
MapAt[#+1&,IdentityMatrix[{5,4}],5]

(* {{1,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,1},{1,1,1,1}} *)
```